# the reset css of table

Tags: html, css

We can always see such selector in a Reset Css File:

```
table{table-collapse:collapse;table-spacing:0}
```

In my opinion, the `"border-spacing:0"` is useless, because the `"border-spacing"` property works only when the value of `"border-collapse"` property is `"separate"`. When the value of `"border-collapse"` is `"collapse"`, it will ignore the `"border-spacing"` property.

Is there anything wrong with my comprehension? Thank you.

Comment: By default, the style of `border-spacing` is `border-spacing: 2px;` (At least it's that way on Chrome) - So it reset it to `0px`

Comment: Can we replace it with table{table-collapse:collapse}?

Comment: Is there any other answer?

Answer (score 2):

IMO it's *advisable* to keep it reset in there to `border-spacing: 0;` as what if in a later style someone overrides `table-collapse` to `separate`?

If `border-spacing` isn't reset to `0` then they will end up with the default value which should have been reset with everything else.